# CSS - computed border color doesn't match actual border color

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have some ordinary buttons with a Tailwind class `border-myCustomColor`. In the computed styles in devtools, all sides are identical. But in the screenshot, you can see that the bottom/right sides are different to the top/left sides.

[image]

BUT

[image]

I'd love to a) fix it; but mostly b) understand how the computed styles could be wrong

If some other effect was being inherited from somewhere, shouldn't that be reflected in the computed styles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using `border-style: outset`.

Try adding `border-style:none`, or `border-style:solid` in your desired border css property. To make it more compact you can also use `border: {width} solid {calculated color}`

See [examples](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp)

Comment: This is correct, thanks, it was the `outset`. For completeness, this is what [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style) says about `border-style: outset`: Displays a border that makes the element appear embossed. It is the opposite of inset. When applied to a table cell with border-collapse set to collapsed, this value behaves like ridge.